# jQuery doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8 ("this" returns DOM instead of jq)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am facing a strange problem and can't find any solution.

[jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) (any version, from 1.7.* to 1.10.*) fails in Internet Explorer 8. All plugins (from bootstrap) and the jQuery library fall with an error:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

[Screenshot from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccbte.png):

[image: screenshot from debugger]

Digging in plugins code, like this:

```
$.fn.alert = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
        //...
    })
}
```

shows the problem: **this** keyword points to **HTMLDomObject**, not on a jQuery object.
What can cause such a weird error?

**Only** in **Internet Explorer 8**!

Comment: jquery version used? if it is jquery 2.x then IE < 9 is not supported

Comment: you have to wrap `this` with jQuery. `$(this)`.

Comment: How do you call that function?

Comment: Evernote is inaccessible to unauthenticated users, please upload your screenshot somewhere else or post the relevant details as plaintext.

Comment: @Bergi, sorry, updated post with new link

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst, not in jquery core and all bootstrap plugins, I think :)

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst - No, this is code for a plugin, and within the plugin `this` should refer to the jQuery object see: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Could you please check whether any other browser add-ons are installed there. In past I faced similar kind of issue in which Pricepeep browser add-on was causing the issue as it was loading its own jQuery version and was not taking care of .noConflict, hence was eating up my jQuery loading in `<head>` section.

Comment: Have you reached out to the jquery support forum? http://forum.jquery.com/

Comment: Does the code work in *other* browsers?  What does the code look like that triggers this error?  Can we get more info or an example that shows the error?  Because jQuery plugins work just fine in IE8.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, yeap, it works great in all other browsers, including ie9

Comment: @visualizer, no, no extensions =(

Comment: Guys, I've found code, that was breaking everything. Updated the post and posted answer

Comment: @ВладимирКорнилов Please, post it as an actual _answer_. Do not write it in the question under a heading "ANSWER" as that makes no sense. You've been here for almost two years, so you should know how it works by now.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've posted but also added to question. Thanx for remark

Comment: @ВладимирКорнилов: Please don't add it to the question. And mark your answer as _accepted_ if it reflects the solution you took. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a piece of code, that caused this problem. I still don't understand, how it could break all jQuery in such way and why it was breaking at all (again, it worked perfectly in all browsers but Internet Explorer 8), but changing the *for in* iterator to $.each() made errors to disappear.

```
for (var i in $postsPortions) {
    var $p = $($postsPortions.get(i));
    var offset = $p.offset();
    if (offset && Math.abs(offset.top - scrollTop) < 100) {
        var year = $p.data('year');
        var season = $p.data('season');
        window.location.hash = year + '/' + season;
        $milestones.removeClass('active');
        $milestones.filter('.year_' + year + '.season_' + season).addClass('active');
        return;
    }
    if (i >= ($postsPortions.length - 1)) return;
}
```

Comment: If your problem was because of your `for in` loop, the you should look into `hasOwnProperty()`. The values `for in` loops grab can be unintuitive, and _can_ change across browsers.

Comment: Have a look at [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration such a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) maybe. If you had posted that code right away we could've helped you.

Comment: @Bergi I have about 2k lines of code in this proj so finding out what code to post was a problem ) Thanx for links. But I still don't understand how this peace of code could totally break everything in the way described in the question (why it changed the behaviour of jQ library)

Answer (score 0):

Some other code or plugin may be loading another JavaScript library and that calling code may not be taking care of `jQuery.noConflict()`. This has happened to me several times. In the meantime, to make your code work, you can also do the following:

```
//If 'this' is pointing to a HTMLDomObject
var obj = $(this)
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use jQuery.each method, "this" (in callback) points to DOM element, not to jQuery wrapper. As follows, you have to wrap "this" in jQuery object:

```
$elements.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    // do something with $this ...
});
```

Comment: But when you make a jQuery plugin, `this` is the jQuery object the plugin was called on.